# Is it possible to disable Google+ notifications of newly Instant Upload photos?

Tags: google-plus, notifications

Is it possible to disable Google+ notifications of newly Instant Upload photos in the big red square at the top right corner of the Google pages?

I would prefer for Google Plus not to notify me about newly uploaded pictures to the Instant Upload folder.

Comment: It is now possible. Go to the Google+ application -> Settings -> Notifications -> and uncheck "Photos added from auto backup"

Comment: @ObAt: that's the mobile app, I think OP is talking about the web interface.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can disable the notifications on your phone (at least on Android) but you cannot on the website. I found [this](http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!msg/google-plus-discuss/JolYBcJmzWs/bRjoMHZXb6IJ) Google Group post where a Google Community Manager actually replied with:

> Hey Brian,
>
> I can understand where you're coming from and will pass the feature
>   request along!
>
> I usually ignore the notifications and sometimes appreciate the
>   reminder that a photo has uploaded when I may have forgotten about it.
>   But I hear you :)
>
> +MrEvan

That was in 8/11. So far the update hasn't been made to say that it's a notification you can turn off. I also ran through settings on the browser and it's definitely not implemented yet.

Comment: I still get them on the top right corner when new images are uploaded. Looking forward to a way of disabling this in the future, when Google+ implements this feature. It would certainly be useful, in my opinion.

Comment: At least on the iPhone (and Android, based on what others are saying), turning off the notifications only turns off push notification popups about new photos. You still get the red bell on Google sites, or within the Google+ app. I hope they fix this. Until then I’ve decided to turn off photo auto backup.

Comment: There are 3 kinds of notifications: on Android (easy to turn of through settings on the device), on the "Google bar" through the bell icon (seems the least problematic to me) but, thirdly, also as an email and this one seems to be impossible to turn off separately?